# Polygon Mesh Processing: result is not manifold

Tags: polygon, mesh, cgal

I'm trying to to the operation Corefinement/Comptuer Difference on tow realitvely simple meshes, with no isolated vertices.
I'm receiving the message:

> WARNING: The result of the requested operation is not manifold and has not been computed.

What can I do in that situation? How to solve the problem?
Thankx in advance.

No idea how to fix that problem.

Comment: Could you share the mesh? If the mesh are clean, there is no solution for now but I'm planning to work on that this summer. The message indicates that the output is not manifold, which can happen if you have a shape that is tangent along an edge to another shape while being (locally) nested